# Is it possible to iterate property names of a (non-instantiated) class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, types

I need to create a configuration object partially based on the properties names of a type/class (typescript).

I can't find, by now, a way to extract property names for the given class, or iterate those.

My class/type:

```
export class DetailedDefaultsObject {
  status: number;
  description?: string;
  model?: any;
}
```

I want to create an object kind of this :

```
{

(status values(numbers/ codes)): {
                       description?: some default value (by status);
                        model?: some default value (by value);
                 } 

}
```

The idea is that, if I want to add any other config by status in my app, I will just need to add this config in DetailedDefaultObject Class, and my logic will always create a new object containing the defaults accordingly with that class (it also could be made using type, I think it would be better, if it is possible...).

Default Values are taken from external objects/dicts.

Comment: TS's type system is [erased](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when compiled to JS, so unless you can do what you want at runtime with pure JS, it's not possible. If your runtime code uses Define semantics for class fields, then you can get even optional key names from an *instance* of the class, as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/w84JAw), but if you need the class *not* to be instantiated, then it's simply impossible. (You could presumably refactor to use a different approach, but that's out of scope). Does that fully address the question?

Comment: @jcalz , I think thats was exactly what i was wanting to know. Makes sense, its impossible to do. By now, I have already find another way to complete the logic of this specific function. Feel free to write a response, I will mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use of `keyof` should work for you:

```js
type PropertiesDefaults = {
    [key in keyof DetailedDefaultsObject]: DetailedDefaultsObject[key]
};
```

Test:

```js
const test: PropertiesDefaults = {
    status: 123;
    description: "abc";
    model: true;
    foo: "bar"; // error
}
```

Comment: Humm.. Interesting. But I was actually looking for a way to do something like a .forEach() in type/class keys, so I could generate my final config object based on that keys. In my given example, each property of the final object represent a status, but for each status I need to generate properties wich names comes from my DetailedDefaultsObject type. If It was a instatiated object, It would work like Object.keys(DetailedDefaultsObject).forEach((propertiesNames) => {   // skip status prop., and creating properties of each status based in propertiesNames    })

Comment: I don't quite understand the point of it. You need to manually map the properties to values anyway, so what's the point of iterating class properties?

Comment: Actually, I wasnt going to map the values manually, I have external objects from wich I am getting default values, by status codes. The Idea is, based in a set of status codes, create a object that has this status codes as keys, and, for each status code, an object that has the properties associated with those status codes. The property name must come from a list of properties (in my case I use that DetailedDefaultsObject class in other parts of my aplication and it could fit), and the values comes from preseted objects like propertyDict = { statusCodeNumber: propertyDefaultValue}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this?

```
interface IExample extends DetailedDefaultsObject {}
```

Example:

```
export class DetailedDefaultsObject {
    status: number;
    description?: string;
    model?: any;
}

interface IExample extends DetailedDefaultsObject {
    foo: number;
}

const Obj: Partial<IExample> = {
    status: 5,
    description: 'desc',
    foo: 1,
}
```

Comment: I don't think extending is a good idea, as it would allow for extra properties.

Answer (score 0):

One time TS type system is erased when code is compiled to JS, it would be impossible to iterate that class that way, as pointed by @jcalz. For my specific case, Ive finnished my logic by create an auxiliar enum and iterating that.